# Disabling Java Integer Cache

Tags: java

Recently stumbled on a problem related to the Java Integer Cache and I'm looking for a way to disable it.

Right now testing is impossible because we can't say it works unless we test with an integer value outside of the cache.

Our case : We had 8 buggy `!=` comparisons and everything worked fine during 2 months of testing because we never had an underlying database entity with a PK higher than 128.

Comment: I hardly think testing is impossible without disabling the cache. If you want an uncached `Integer`, initialize it with `new Integer(1);`. Also fire the person who was making object comparisons with `!=`.

Comment: There's more to this story.  How were you comparing these integers?  Were they *both* objects?  I'm willing to bet that the developer that wrote that assumed at some point an unboxing would occur, but could that have ever been the case in your code?

Comment: Since you now know about the problem, you can easily change your tests so primary key values are above 128. Much better solution that trying to hack the `Integer` class.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You don't. The integer cache is an implementation detail of `Integer`. If you use `Integer`, you accept the cache. It's a good thing, there to reduce the number of effectively duplicate objects which may be created.

Use [FindBugs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FindBugs) to locate spurious integer reference comparisons and replace them with [`Integer.equals`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#equals(java.lang.Object)) -- that is the proper way to fix the problems you're encountering.

If problems which are this fundamental to the language are present in your application then I strongly suggest running a full suite of static analysis tests and working your way through to triage them.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest thing to do to address and catch this kind of bug is to write a unit test that has a primary key arbitrarily (and randomly) higher than 128.

This gives you:

- An `Integer` out of the `IntegerCache`
- A way to independently validate this without having to change any runtime parameters (i.e. easily repeatable on developer boxes)
- Concise documentation in the form of tests that states that you want to be sure that these values are actually being accounted for

You do not need to disable JVM internals to test this.  You just need to be aware of their limitations and test around them if their case poses a challenge for your application.

Answer (score 0):

Since Java 6 introduced Escape Analysis I see no benefit in pooling temporary objects such as Integer. Moreover, Integer cache being "unpredictable" sometimes can prevent Escape Analysis from functioning properly.

Java 8 Escape Analysis can't do scalar replacement of Integer objects if Integer cache is enabled. (Java 13 seems to be doing well either way)

Disabling Integer cache is not supported officially, but it can be done with this code snippet:

```
public static Unsafe getUnsafe() {
    try {
        Field theUnsafe = Unsafe.class.getDeclaredField("theUnsafe");
        theUnsafe.setAccessible(true);
        return (Unsafe) theUnsafe.get(null);
    } catch (NoSuchFieldException | IllegalArgumentException | IllegalAccessException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
}

public static void disableIntegerCache() {
    try {
        Class<?> clazz = Class.forName("java.lang.Integer$IntegerCache");
        Field cache = clazz.getDeclaredField("cache");
        Field low = clazz.getDeclaredField("low");
        Field high = clazz.getDeclaredField("high");

        Unsafe unsafe = getUnsafe();

        Object base = unsafe.staticFieldBase(low);
        long lowOffset = unsafe.staticFieldOffset(low);
        long highOffset = unsafe.staticFieldOffset(high);
        long cacheOffset = unsafe.staticFieldOffset(cache);

        unsafe.putObjectVolatile(base, cacheOffset, new Integer[0]);
        unsafe.putIntVolatile(base, lowOffset, Integer.MAX_VALUE);
        unsafe.putIntVolatile(base, highOffset, Integer.MIN_VALUE);
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException | NoSuchFieldException | IllegalArgumentException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

I use MAX_VALUE and MIN_VALUE because of weird behavior related to JVM intrinsics in `valueOf` method.

Answer (score -2):

You can set the size of the cache using Java Options. The following will let you set the cache as you wish:

```
-XX:AutoBoxCacheMax=<CACHE_SIZE>
```

for instance:

```
-XX:AutoBoxCacheMax=1
```

Comment: @Makoto, while I agree that you don't need to disable the cache in order to test, this is the working answer to the question, so I don't see the reason to downvote it.

Comment: You actually can't reduce the cache size using this method. If 127 is larger than this value, 127 is used. [See this line](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8u40-b25/java/lang/Integer.java#793)

Comment: @Makoto Obviously this isn't the real answer. But I don't find that downvoting is appropriate here. It *solves* the issue, and is actually something I wasn't aware of.

Comment: @GhostCat:  If it isn't the real answer, how could it solve anything?!

Comment: @Michael Now **your** argument gives reason to downvote. Because if true, the answer is simply *wrong*, and thus not answering the question!

Comment: @AR1:  A "correct" answer in the most technical sense may still be the wrong answer for the practical case.

Comment: @GhostCat @AR1 the code in `IntegerCache` will still set it to `[-128, 127]`. This option can only increase the default value, `-XX:AutoBoxCacheMax=1` will have no effect.

Comment: @Makoto There is sometimes room for debate. If it *would* work, then it might be a quick fix, for example to get things going for the time you re-design your solution.